# How to determine which 1H bar produced the low of the day?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to calculate which bar (of the 24-hour bars in a day), produced the low for the day. This I want to calculate only for days that produced a green bar on 1D.

The code below practically waits until the first hour bar of the day (01h00), then checks whether yesterday was a green bar on 1D and then looks back 24-hour bars to determine which one of them produced the low for the day. Or that is what it's supposed to do. The results from this code are confusing and I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any advice would be highly appreciated, thanks.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Low of day bar")

endOfDay = 0100 //session end, in exchange local time, in 24hours format: 9:30AM=930, 4pm=1600
lastBarOfDay = (hour(time_close)*60 + minute(time_close)==(60*(endOfDay/100)+endOfDay%100))?1:0

dayIsGreen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)[1] >= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)[1]

longSLBar = 0

if lastBarOfDay == 1 and dayIsGreen
    longSLBar := ta.lowestbars(low, 24)[2] //without current bar
    
    label.new(bar_index, low, text =str.tostring(longSLBar))
    

plot(longSLBar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The code:

```
ta.lowestbars(low, 24)[1]
```

Needed to run every single iteration, so I moved it out of the if statement.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Low of day bar")

endOfDay = 0100 //session end, in exchange local time, in 24hours format: 9:30AM=930, 4pm=1600
lastBarOfDay = (hour(time_close)*60 + minute(time_close)==(60*(endOfDay/100)+endOfDay%100))?1:0

dayIsGreen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)[1] >= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)[1]

var int longSLBar = na

last24bars = ta.lowestbars(low, 24)[1]

if lastBarOfDay == 1 and dayIsGreen
    longSLBar := last24bars
    
    label.new(bar_index, low, text =str.tostring(longSLBar))
    

plot(longSLBar)
```